# How can I create a stacked bar chart from this table

Tags: datatables, powerbi, bar-chart, stacked-chart

I am new to PowerBI so please bear with me.

I have this table:

```
RespondentID         Question 1                Question 2                    Question 3
 1          Neither Agree or Disagree            Agree                         Agree
 2                    Disagree                   Agree                         Agree
 3          Neither Agree or Disagree    Neither Agree or Disagree       Neither Agree or Disagree
 4                    Agree                      Disagree                Neither Agree or Disagree
```

and I want to view it as a stacked bar chart, showing the question number to the left and for each question, a bar coloured depending on the count of values (disagree, agree, neither)

Thanks,

Comment: you need to unpivot your table so that question number becomes a column.

Answer (score 0):

Your table isn't in a good model for the kind of visualization you're trying to create.  It must be 'unpivoted.'

So, highlight your table by right clicking it and choose 'Edit Query.'  When the Power Query Editor window loads, you should see your table in the editing area.  Right click the ID column and select 'Unpivot other columns.'  Rename 'Attribute' to 'Question' and 'Value' to 'Answer'

Close and apply.

Now you can create your stacked bar.  Drag 'Answer' to the value dwell, it will automatically become 'count of answer.'  Drag 'Answer' again to Legend.  You'll get your stacked column effect.  And then add 'Question' to Axis.

Good luck, hope it helps.